# How to get text from xhtml

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xhtml

```html
<div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend class="lheader">Section Information:</legend>
    <span id="lblSectionInfo">
        Name:
        <font style="font-weight:normal">rr</font>
        <br>
        Type:
        <font style="font-weight:normal">Section Type     </font>
        Section List:
        <font style="font-weight:normal"> Yes       </font>
        Status:
        <font style="font-weight:normal">
        Section:
        <font style="font-weight:normal">Section Condition</font>
        <br>
    </span>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I have to get the text from the above Section Information section of the screen.
I tried `getText()` and it returns blank row, tried `getAttribute("innerText")` and it returns N/A, tried `getAttribute("innerHTML")` and it returns N/A

Not sure how I can get the complete text or individual test e.g. Section Name 
should return text Section "RR" etc. The Xpath I am using is correct.
Any help is really appreciated.
Fyi, I am using Xpath below to get the text.

```
//div[@id = 'TestView5']//span[@id = 'lblSectionInfo']
```

My Xpath is correct as I am able to highlight the complete text on this section when use it by Selenium IDE.

Comment: There is no such thing as read only elements in HTML. Please show the statements in full

Comment: What are you passing to `getText()`? What is your `xpath` selector?

Comment: I hope this will help you https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_element.asp

Comment: Post your actual code that you are using.

Comment: The example is not well-formed XML. Perhaps the resulting N/A is caused by an error handler somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite difficult to separate those fields because they are under the same span node. I can see two workarounds.
1. Use index of `<font>` node as an anchor.

```
Name: "//span[@id='lblSectionInfo']/font[1]"
Type: "//span[@id='lblSectionInfo']/font[2]"
Section List: "//span[@id='lblSectionInfo']/font[3]"
```

2. Use JavaScript to find the text nodes to get field names, and then use Selenium to find the `<font>` node to get their values. Finally, map them together.

```
function getTextNode(rootNode) {
    var nodes = rootNode.childNodes;
    var fieldNames = [];
    var count=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if ((nodes[i].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)) {
            if(nodes[i].textContent.trim().indexOf(':')>0) {
                let text = nodes[i].textContent.trim();
                fieldNames[count] = text.substring(0,text.length-1);
            }           
        }
    }
    return fieldNames;
}
```

Comment: The first workaround works perfect for me. Thnx Buaban.